# Silicon-graphene battery energy density?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion

A startup called [CalBattery](http://www.clbattery.com/) is touting that their silicon-graphene anodes for li-ion batteries "will improve the anode specific capacity performance of lithium battery anodes by a factor of 3X."

Will a 3X improvement in anode performance translate into a 3X improvement in energy density of the overall battery, or not? (In other words, is battery energy density anode-limited?)

Comment: oh i went to a seminar on this but i cant remember which!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, energy density of a battery is not anode-limited. Yes, there will be improvement, but not a 3X energy density increase.

Comment: Thanks! Ballpark, what would you guess the energy density increase would be? And what resources would you suggest I use to figure out what the increase would be?

Comment: Battery design is a pretty involved black art, and my own knowledge is peripheral at best. Hnece not really qualified to "guess" at the energy density increase. What I can say for certain, though, is that the increase would vary across battery sizes, electrode dimensions, and temperature... and probably a whole bunch of other factors.